# What is the difference between client and user?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I  have EJB methods .I try to call EJB methods from the User interface it may be a JSF, or JSP.I don't know the exact difference between user and client.can anyone help me.
Questions asked during my interview

Comment: Client is the machine (user agent for web), user is a person logged in with a session; or it can be "Guest" or "Anonymous" if your system supports it. "User Interface" is what a _person_ would see. Machines (clients) interface using APIs, RMI, message passing, or similar techniques.

Answer (score 6):

Client may be a tool like any web browser or may be any desktop application. A user is a person who will log into the client and consume or use the remote functionality exposed by the server. Everytime user wants to access any functionality, client will make a call to server and it will show the response received from server on client after parsing. 
Multiple users may log onto a client. Every user will have separate login credentials.